# Conditionally rendering Navigator in v5

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Any reason not to conditionally render some Navigator in react-navigation v5?

When looking at the documentation for the Auth flow, everything is done to make sure the Navigator is always rendered. Is it a bad idea to mount/unmount Navigators?

For example, is it ok to do this:

```js
<>
      {isLoading ? (
        <SplashScreen/>
      ) : (
        <NavigationNativeContainer>
          {userToken ? <HomeStackNavigator/> : <SignInStackNavigator/>}
        </NavigationNativeContainer>
      )}
</>
```

instead of this:

```js
<NavigationNativeContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
          {isLoading ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen}/>
          ) : state.userToken === null ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen}/>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
          )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationNativeContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to do it this way, but keeping the same navigator will animate any state changes, e.g. when user signs in, the `Home` screen will animate in. Changing the navigator means getting rid of previous navigator's state and using a new navigator.

You can also keep the Splash screen outside the navigator and only keep `SignIn` and `Home` screen in the stack navigator. Depends on how you want the animations to look.